# Do 2 queries need to be submitted to the database to get total count and paged section using EF / Linq to Entities?

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, pagination, entity-framework-4.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Better way to query a page of data and get total count in entity framework 4.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767409/better-way-to-query-a-page-of-data-and-get-total-count-in-entity-framework-4-1)

When implementing pagination using EF / LINQ to entities, I am familiar with using `Skip()` and `Take()` to decide which paginated section to display. I am also familiar with using `Count()` before invoking `Skip()` or `Take()` to get the total number of (non-paginated) results being paged over.

My question is, does this always have to ultimately end up in 2 separate queries being sent to the db? I would think yes, since we need to invoke Count() first to get the total (`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM...`), then extend the expression tree with Skip/Take, then invoke again to get the actual data (`SELECT * FROM...`).

I vaguely remember reading about a trick in SQL 2k8 that made getting total row counts easier, but I doubt EF / LINQ to Entities supports this provider feature. Just asking the question to see if anyone knows how to consolidate these into a single database hit.

Comment: Yes it is, thank you for the link.