# EF 4.0 make batch query to get count of resultset but return only top 5 records

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework-4

Is there a way to get count of resultset but return only top 5 records while making just one db hit instead of 2 (one for count and second for data)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Paging in Entity Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049825/paging-in-entity-framework)

Answer (score 3):

There is not a particularly good way to do this in Entity Framework, at least as of v4.  @Tobias writes a single LINQ query, but his suspicions are correct.  You'll see multiple queries roll by in SQL Profiler.

Ignoring EF for a minute, this is a relatively complicated problem for SQL Server.  Well, it's complicated once your data size gets large or your query gets complicated.  You can get a flavor for [what's involved here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038506/efficient-way-of-getting-rowcount-from-a-query-using-row-number/4383164#4383164).

With that said, I wouldn't worry about it being 2 queries just yet.  Don't optimize until you know it is an actual performance problem. You'll likely end up working around EF, maybe using the EF extensions and creating a stored proc that can take advantage of windowed functions and CTE's.  Or maybe it will just return two result sets in a single procedure.

Answer (score 1):

This little query should do the trick (I'm not sure if that's really just one physical query though, and it *could* be that the grouping is done in the code rather than in the DB), but it's definitely more convenient:

```
var obj = (from x in entities.SomeTable
          let item = new { N = 1, x }
          group item by item.N into g
          select new { Count = g.Count(), First = g.Take(5) }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Nonetheless, just doing this in two queries will definitely be much faster (especially if you define them in *one* stored procedure, as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1071705/880802)).

Comment: @Ankit: Right... forgot one `=`. It's fixed now.

Comment: This does not reduce the db hits and still hits database twice. So no use :(